What are all the different possible positive differences of the numerator and denominator in a reduced fraction?
I was solving this problem and had to find all possible positive differences of the numerator and denominator of $\frac{a}{a+10}$ in lowest terms. I noticed it is $1, 2, 5,$ and $10$, which are all the divisors of 10. Could someone help explain why this is the case?

When you divide numerator and denominator by $d:=\gcd(a,a+10)=\gcd(a,10)\in{1,2,5,10}$, the difference beteeen numerator and denominator becomes $\frac{10}d$

When you divide numerator and denominator by
$d:=\gcd(a,a+10)=\gcd(a,10)\in\{1,2,5,10\}$,
the difference between denominator and numerator becomes $\dfrac{a+10}d-\dfrac ad=\dfrac{10}d.$
